Does an abstract class get instantiated by its subclass?
While you cannot make an instance of an abstract class, in this example the super keyword is used to reference the instance variable of the super class, hence a reference that is provided in the abstract class.
public abstract class Abstract {

    protected int n1;
    protected int n2;

    public Abstract(int n1, int n2) {
        this.n1 = n1;
        this.n2 = n2;
    }
}


public class Instance extends Abstract {

    public Instance(int n1, int n2) {
        super(n1, n2);
    }

    public int makeSum() {
        return super.n1 + super.n2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instance myInstance = new Instance(1, 2);
        System.out.println(myInstance.makeSum());
    }
}

Is there an instance of the abstract class created "in the background" - or how do I have to read this?

There is only one instance that includes "both" or "everything". Think of it like that: When you want to create an instance of a Dog, before that can happen, Java first has to give that instance everything from the Animal class. And then it can put the Dog specific stuff "on top" to create the actual Dog instance. Hence, any Dog is also an Animal.

It's just a naming convention. When you change a field you can use a = 1 or you can use this.a=1 that gives you the ability to specificy the field  a vs a local variable. The same goes for 'super' if you happened to shadow a field.

In your example there is only one instance. It contains members defined in its class and its parent class. super is used to reference members defined in the parent.
